# How can I allow for the modifications of properties that are initialized in the constructor of an inherited control (button) C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, button, inheritance, default-value

I am trying to create an inherited control that will have some default values that would save me some time since these controls are to be the same on each form.

I have created 2 class for this. A base class that Inherit UltraButton where I put the values that will be common to all the buttons. In this case the ButtonStyle, image size and the control size.

Here is the class :

```
    public class BaseButton : Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraButton
{
    public BaseButton()
    {
        //We set the properties of the base object.
        ButtonStyle = Infragistics.Win.UIElementButtonStyle.Popup;
        ImageSize = new Size(32, 32);
        Size = new Size(100, 62);
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public new Size Size
    {
        get { return base.Size; }

        set { base.Size = value; }
    }
}
```

Now I need to create a Reset button (that inherits from BaseButton) that will specify the image to use for the ResetBt, the Text and the default anchoring for the control :

```
public class ResetBt : BaseButton
{
    private readonly string _text;

    public ResetBt()
    {
        Appearance.Image = Properties.Resources.Restart_32_32;
        _text = "&Reset";
        base.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
    }
}
```

This is where I noticed a problem. If I try to change the Anchor setting at design-time I can but at run time the values passed to the constructor override anything that was input at design-time. That behavior is fine for the image of the button and the Text value but for other properties like Anchor this is not suitable.

What is the best approach to pass default values to some properties of an inherited control and still allow for their modification at design-time ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try additional constructors:

```
        public BaseButton(Image image, Anchor anchor)
        {
            Image = image;
            Anchor = anchor
        }


 public ResetBt(Image image,Anchor anchor): Base(Image image,Anchor anchor)
    {

        _text = "&Reset";

    }
```

Comment: I am sorry but that doesn't work. I can't get this to compile and by default the designer will take the default constructor. Maybe I don't understand... If you can clarify I will give it a try. The goal here is that when I drag and drop the control on the form I get the "default" value set in the inherited control in the properties window. That value needs to be editable and used at run-time... I've also tried to override the Anchor property without success. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You'll have to add it programmatically may be able to open the designer file and make an edit after you drag it on the form

Comment: There has to be another way to do this. I'll keep searching. If anyone else can pitch in would be greatly appreciated.